# I want to post on Facebook and Twitter every day is there any technique to call method every day at any particular time ?? 

Tags: iphone

I have a requirement: I want to call method every day at any particular time if possible.

Comment: Please stop editing your question like this. It adds no new information and makes it difficult to determine your issue.

Comment: Sorry I was trying to change immediately after post but because of slow net speed It can't reflect sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

You can set a `UILocalNotification` to remind the user to open your app, but they are under no obligation to do so.